# Sublime Text Keybinding with two 'wildcard' characters

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm trying to develop a Package that needs a Keybinding like this:

```
{ 
    "keys": [",", "<character>", "<character>"], 
    "command": "super_awesome"
}
```

That works, meaning that Sublime expects two characters after I press `,`, but from the plugin I can't access both characters. Sublime only supplies the package with

```
class SuperAwesomeCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(edit, **args):
        print(args) # => { 'character': '2nd character pressed' }
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks!